# Error: org.json.me.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1 of [

Tags: blackberry

how to solve error “org.json.me.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1 of [” in black berry

Comment: Can you post the entire JSON String?

Comment: Not a real question. No details about what, where, ... -> -1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, the error is showing that you are getting the values in `JSONArray` and you are trying to get it in `JSONObject`, so change your JSONObject to `JSONArray` when you are getting the response.

You might be getting output in

`[] = JSONArray` not in

```
{} = JSONObject
```

Hope it works thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Examples of valid JSON objects:

{} is used by Objects

```
{name: "Oh Chin Boon", age: "24"}
```

[] is used by Arrays

```
[ {name: "Oh Chin Boon", age: "24"}, {name: "Ken", age: "33"} ]
```